# AzureDevops PowerShell and Tasks

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I currently have a VSTS/AzureDevOps task extension which is composed of a `json` file and a `ps1` script. The `json` file basically stipulates the inputs and the `ps1` script does it's thing (it runs some tests.) I want to extend this task to upload test results in the pipeline, and AzureDevops has the handy "Publish Test Results", but thats a `YAML` thing.

Is there any way to get the same functionality as using the premade task, but just via PowerShell? I looked at things like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/Commands.md) but I could not find something obvious.

I assume the only other route for doing this would be somehow using the AzureDevops REST api?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "Publish Test Results" is a YAML thing ?  to publish files and folders there are logging-commands that you can use like this one -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#artifact-commands . Just write to the host, the Pipeline-Agent picks up your command and processes it

Comment: the link you posted already does the same thing as what i linked but has it wrapped in functions which is nicer to use. i think "Write-VstsAssociateArtifact" might even be what you are looking for but i'm nut sure

Comment: @D.J. What I mean is that the feature "Publish Test Result" is easy to use in the visual designer. But I don't understand how to get the same thing done using pure powershell. [GitHub indicates that I can use "artifact.upload"](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/issues/219), but the docs are somewhat lacking.

Comment: May i know how you ran the tests in your ps1 scripts? If you invoke dotnet test or vstest to run tests in scripts, then you can just publish test result with dotnet or vstest.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT The tests are executed by a homemade testframework (some customized node thing). I've convinced the dev to add junit xml outputs to his code, so now we can produce a junit xml file result file. Currently I obtain the xml file from an HTTP endpoint, and I want to push it to Azure pipelines now.

Comment: @Svend can you specifie _"I want to extend this task to upload test results in the pipeline"_? what do you want to upload? single values or a bunch of values, more like a file? what do want to do with the upload? processing in background? visualize in charts?

Comment: The homemade framework runs on a server out there. It has an HTTP endpoint that returns a JUnit formatted xml file, containing the test run results. I think I'm beginning to understand how those logging commands function, so I will give those a shot now (JUnit is a standard java unit test framework, AzureDevops can parse junit formatted files, so that's why Im using that, I just want Azure to display the results in the portal, pretty basic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested `artifact.upload` following the example given [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md). and found out it published the file to the artifacts, and can not show the test result in the `Tests` page of build `Summary` as shown in below pic.
[image]

Tested with `artifact.upload` with below script in powershell.

```
echo "##vso[artifact.upload containerfolder=testresult;artifactname=uploadedresult;]$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\TestResult\WS-LEVIL-01_WS-LEVIL-01_2019-09-05_11_36_44.trx"
```

the task log showed as below:

```
Uploading 1 files
File upload succeed.
Upload 'C:\agent\_work\2\TestResult\WS-LEVIL-01_WS-LEVIL-01_2019-09-05_11_36_44.trx' to file container: '#/3389084/testresult'
Associated artifact 209 with build 595
Async Command End: Upload Artifact
```

I tried to do this with pure powershell and seemed be a hard work. If you only want to publish it to azure pipeline and want to show the results like above pic. You can save the xml file to a place on the host agent and then use `Publish Test Result` task to pulish the xml test result. This seems like a easier workaround.

Comment: Could you give the full example string you used for the `artifact.upload` logging command? Then I think this should qualify as answered. After talking with coworkers, it does look as if what we'll end up doing is output a variable containing the filenames, and then use a follow up `Publish Test Result` as you suggest.

Comment: I updated the example string, Hope it be of some help.